# vichuploadbundle and KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors (translatable) [Symfony]

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I use the bundle KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors (translatable) for to manage my translation.

I use also the bundle vichuploadbundle to manage my img.

I have an entity that must have different images depending on languages, so I placed my img field and the annotation Vich\UploadField in my entityTranslatable entity.
But I can't display the image on Twig... I have this error :

[Error display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHSvj.png)

This is my twig code :

```
{{  vich_uploader_asset(creation, 'imageCreation ') }}
```

And this, my entity code :

```
/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="image_creation", fileNameProperty="image")
 * @var File
 */
private $imageCreation;
```

**EDIT:**

it's ok for my first problem. But now I have an error because the mapping of my image field is not found... How mapping this ? Because my image field is'nt in my Creation entity but in my CreationTranslation entity ?

[Display error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StESA.png)

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Message seems clear enough : place @Vich\Uploadable on top of your Creation Entity.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the documentation https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
    class Creation
    {

    }
```

Comment: Thank for quick response, it's ok for my first problem.

But now I have an error because the mapping of my image field is not found... How mapping this ? Because my image field is'nt in my Creation entity but in my CreationTranslation entity ?